# Getting the inner element of a XML which has html style of format

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I want to get the text value of an XML node. I am using DOM and everything is working fine.

I would like to get the node's value in following scenario

```
<student>
   <name><h1>Abcd</h1></name>
</student>
```

In the above case i am not able to get the full text value, I am getting only Abcd once i parse the document.

Below is the code,

```
String path = "path_of_the_file";
    File file = new File(path);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

    Node student = doc.getElementsByTagName("student").item(0);
    NodeList nodes = student.getChildNodes();
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
         if(nodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
             Node element = nodes.item(i);
             System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You cannot get it as text because the HTML under the name node is not plain text but ordinary XML. You should get the h1 node as DOM and then serialize it to text.

Comment: Could you please provide samples? I tried with getFirstChild and it is not working.

Comment: I think this will help you, seems to be a very similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873393/get-node-raw-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get node raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873393/get-node-raw-text)